# CSS: Shadow in a triangle

Tags: html, css

I have this triangle in CSS:

```css
.triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 200px 200px 0 0;
  border-color: #007bff transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

How can I apply a 1px shadow on the hypotenuse line?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Since `box-shadow` won't work, you have to apply a drop shadow filter on the triangle:

```css
.triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 200px 200px 0 0;
  border-color: #007bff transparent transparent transparent;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
  filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Create a `polygon` in an `svg`, then apply a [`drop-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow) filter.

```css
.triangle {
  width: 200px;
  color: #007bff;
  filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5));
}
```

```html
<svg class="triangle" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <polygon points="0,0 100,0 0,100" fill="currentColor" />
</svg>
```

Try to use semantic, meaningful HTML elements instead of relying purely on CSS for shapes.

Answer (score 5):

You can make this *without using borders* by employing an angled gradient.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 2em auto;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #007bff 50%, rgba(0,0,0,.5) 50%, transparent 52%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: While this code *does work*, it uses a gradient instead of a “real” drop shadow which makes it a bit harder to control the shadow effect. Also, it does not render nicely – the shadow is cut off because the actual box is a rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

Working for me with this code:

```css
.triangle-use-dropshadow{
content: ' ';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 14px solid;
    border-color: #fdfdfd transparent transparent transparent;
    filter: drop-shadow(-2px -4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle-use-dropshadow"></div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).